# Is it possible to output photorec files to ssh account directly

Tags: linux

Photorec question: I would like to pipe the files directly to a ssh account rather than a folder on local machine. Is this possible on linux ubuntu? below is the code i tried but it don't work any ideas or code plz.

```
photorec | ssh User@Some_IP_Address /d /path_to_folder/  /cmd /dev/sdc fileopt,everything,disable,jpg,enable,freespace,search
```

Comment: What error did you get, if any?

Comment: Don't get any errors, asks for pwd and then just hangs, I've check ssh account to see if anything has been uploaded but nothing.